# Create SQL database from text files using R

Tags: python, sql, r

I have 10 csv's each about 7 Gb; the files are not indexed. The machine I'm working on has 32 Gb ram - this can't change for data privacy reasons. I'd like to create a SQL database (slight preference for SQLite but am not married to it) to make future querying easier. Preferred solution would be implemented in R but I am familiar with Python so that'd be okay as well. I'm aware of the RSQLite library but correct me if I wrong in thinking that R would have to load all of the files into memory?

Comment: you can load one file at a time and save it to your sqlite db file.

Comment: @chinsoon12 I'm new to this SQL stuff so bare with me, once all files are loaded into the database could I then query them all as if they were one? That is, could I conceptually think of it as a giant data frame or would I have to perform some joining operations? Given my memory limit, is that feasible?

Comment: it depends on how you want to structure your database. you can rowbind all your 10csvs or keep them separate and join them in the sqlquery. if you query doesnt exceed 32gb, u r prob fine. try and discover and internalize.

Comment: check out fread from data.table.  If it can't gulp it, it can take a "bite at a time" using "skip" and "nrows".